# Promises not waiting on prior then statements to complete.

Tags: node.js, promise

I am trying to post to a /user/create route data from a form which all comes through fine and then have it check one by one that the data is valid and in some cases unique in the database. Here is what I am using to check the User and the Email address entered on the registration form.

The function seems to query properly, but in the end, my console.log of the error messages I am collecting is only collecting the first entry.

```
// Check if variable is already is available or not
var existsInDatabase = function(field, value){

  var deferred = Q.defer();
  var query = {};
  var errorMessage = {};

  query[field] = value;

  User.find(query, function(err, docs){
    // If it finds it, then set a message for already existing
    if(docs){
        errorMessage = {'type': 'alert', 'body': value + ' already exists in the database.'}
        deferred.resolve(errorMessage);
    } else {
        deferred.reject( value + ' was not found in the database');
    }

  });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Here is where I check the passwords to see if they match.

```
var doPasswordsMatch = function(password, confirmed){
  var deferred = Q.defer();

  console.log('Values passed into doPasswordsMatch() function:', password + ' ' + confirmed);

  if(password !== confirmed){
    errorMessage = {'type': 'alert', 'body': 'The two passwords you entered do not match'};
    deferred.resolve(errorMessage);
  };

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Here is my route with the .then chaining.

```
router.post('/user/create', function(req, res){

  var errorMessages = [];

  existsInDatabase('userName', req.body.username)
    .then(function(errorMessage){ if (errorMessage) { errorMessages.push(errorMessage) } })
    .then(existsInDatabase('userEmail', req.body.email))
    .then(function(errorMessage){ if (errorMessage) { errorMessages.push(errorMessage) } })
    .then(doPasswordsMatch(req.body.password, req.body.confirmedPassword))
    .then(function(errorMessage){ if (errorMessage) { errorMessages.push(errorMessage) } })
    .then(function(){ console.log(errorMessages); });

});
```

I guess where I am struggling is the chaining of .then and how to prevent something from triggering unless everything before it is completed.

Comment: Why are you sometimes passing functions and sometimes promises to `then`? Would you expect `.then(console.log(errorMessages))` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`then()` takes functions as parameters ([full specification](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-22)), but you're passing in promises for your 2nd and 4th `.then()`. It should work if you wrap them in anonymous functions instead.

```
...
.then(function() { return existsInDatabase('userEmail', req.body.email); })
...
.then(function() { return doPasswordsMatch(req.body.password, req.body.confirmedPassword); })
...
```

`return` is so the promises returned by `existsInDatabase()` and `doPasswordsMatch()` are resolved before moving on to the next `then()`

However, you may need to rethink the way your logic is set up. The way it is currently, if the passwords do match, the next `.then` is never called, and the logic just gets stuck.